# Given a block of text, how to vertically center w one line. But grow to support 2 lines of text?

Tags: html, css

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LGzdf/

What I want to do is some how vertically align the text to 50% if there is only 1 lines worth of text.

But if there is two lines, with just css, it should fill the entire space having a height equal to the image.

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find this [article](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/) useful.

Play around with something like this:

```
.mod-item {
    ...
    overflow:hidden;
}
.story {
    height:30px;
    display: table;
}
.mod-item .title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 30px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGzdf/1/)